# Disable the bot with a command in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Is it possible to do such thing? For what I understood you should use `if (enabled == true)` but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a global variable (e.g. `client.isPaused`) and check its value. Check out the code snippet below:

```js
const client = new Client();
const prefix = '!';

// enabled by default
client.isPaused = false;

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  // the only command allowed when bot is paused
  if (command === 'unpause') {
    if (!client.isPaused)
      return message.channel.send(
        `The bot is already listening to commands, can't unpause it.`,
      );

    client.isPaused = false;

    return message.channel.send(`The bot is listening to your commands again.`);
  }

  // if bot is paused, exit so the commands below will not get executed
  if (client.isPaused) return;

  if (command === 'pause') {
    client.isPaused = true;
    return message.channel.send(
      `The bot is paused. Use \`${prefix}unpause\` to unpause it.`,
    );
  }

  if (command === 'ping') {
    return message.channel.send('Pong!');
  }

  if (command === 'time') {
    return message.channel.send(
      `The time is ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}`,
    );
  }
});

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot is connected...');
});
```

[image]